# What's the point of public interfaces in Go?

Tags: go

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces says:

Go interfaces generally belong in the package that uses values of the interface type, not the package that implements those values

Then, couldn't most of the interfaces be private then?

```
package mypackage

type thinger interface {
  Thing() bool
}

func Smth(t thinger) bool {...}
```

```
package otherpackage

type MyThing struct{}
func (t MyThing) Thing() bool {return true}

myVar := MyThing{}
mypackage.Smth(myVar)
```

What's the point of public interfaces? What are the benefits of e.g. `io.Reader` being a public interface?

Comment: 1. There is no point in making these interfaces "private".  Private types and fields help hiding implementation details, your `thinger` doesn't hide implementation details.

Comment: 2. mypackage would not display thinger and nobody would know which methods must be present on a type so that it can be given to mypackage.Smth.

Comment: 3. You cannot augment mypackage: You cannot provide a functions `func Other(x mypackage.thinger)` which works on all thingers.

Comment: Summary: No benefit, just drawbacks.

Comment: "What are the benefits of e.g. io.Reader being a public interface?" Other packages can declare functions that use `io.Reader` and users of that package know what to expect. Same for every public interface.

Answer (score 6):

The interface is also a contract. Taking [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/?tab=doc#Reader) for example; it has a specific behavior that all implementations must abide by, and using that as an argument or return type documents what behavior you expect, along with the method signatures. The inverse is true too, in that for types with overlapping method sets, if you happen to have the same method but don't adhere to a particular interface, you can use a different interface name to distinguish the two (which may not be a good pattern within a codebase, but often external interfaces are encountered that may need to be differentiated).

When you define a method or function of some sort using `io.Reader`, you get to rely on all the documented behavior of `io.Reader` without having to document it each and every time within your own code.

Go types are not variant, so you could not declare a function signature that satisfies another with a private interface. If there was a function `func ReadFrom(r internal)`, you could not satisfy that function signature with your own `func ReadFrom(r myInternal)`. There are numerous examples of this in the standard library, which you could not implement if the interfaces were private; for example

- [`io.ReaderFrom`](https://pkg.go.dev/io?tab=doc#ReaderFrom)
- [`io.WriterTo`](https://pkg.go.dev/io?tab=doc#WriterTo)
- [`net.Listener`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/?tab=doc#Listener)
- [`net.Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/?tab=doc#Conn)
- [`http.Handler`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/?tab=doc#Handler)
- [`http.handlerFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/?tab=doc#HandlerFunc)

Finally, well-known interfaces also help with simply reading and understanding code. `io.Reader` is a known interface, and easily recognizable within the source. When encountering `myReader`, you don't know what the expected behavior is, or even what the method set is, without consulting the documentation.

Comment: @dmzkrsk: you couldn't then use it in your own function signatures, like `func ReadFrom(r io.Reader, x myType)`.

Comment: Well, my `ReadFrom` calls  a specific method of `r`, so I can declare an ad-hoc interface `myReader` in my package, and `ReadFrom(r myReader)` will work for `io.Reader` as well

Comment: A case of well-known standard library interfaces sounds plausible, but I still see no benefits in general case

Comment: @dmzkrsk: the design of the go libraries relies on shared interfaces. The first example that comes to mind is that you can't implement [`http.Handler`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http?tab=doc#Handler) (or `HandlerFunc`) without using `http.ResponseWriter`. This is quite a useful property to just throw away for no reason other than "because you can".